# How to express Allan variance without neglecting clock drift

Tags: experimental-physics, time

[Allan variance, $\sigma^2[ \tau ]$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Allan_variance), or its square root ([Allan deviation, $\sigma[ \tau ]$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Allan_deviation)) is a quantity (as function of parameter $\tau$) which is said to be a measure of (or related to) "stability of clocks".

For a recent example cmp. ["*First accuracy evaluation of NIST-F2*" (T. P. Heavner *et al.*)](http://iopscience.iop.org/0026-1394/51/3/174/), especially

> "*Figure 1. The Total deviation (TOTDEV) of NIST-F2*".

Clearly, this quantity is referring to **one** clock **itself**; e.g. "the *NIST-F2*" in the article.

However, the Wikipedia page points out that for ["*practical measurements*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Practical_measurements):

> ["*All measurements of Allan variance will in effect be the comparison of two different clocks [...] a reference clock and a device under test (DUT).*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Measurement)

Likewise, the article on the *NIST-F2* states that

> "*The measurement was made using a commercial hydrogen maser as a reference.*"

With two clocks being involved, there's necessarily concern about [clock drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift); indeed:

> ["*[...] drift will contribute to [the raw] output result. When measuring a real system, the linear drift or other drift mechanism may need to be estimated and removed from the time-series prior to calculating the Allan variance.*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Linear_response)

**My question:**

Can you please give an expression (as explicitly as reasonably achievable here)
of this mentioned "(raw) ***output result* before** [*post-processing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Post-processing)",
in terms of

- the [total phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Oscillator_model) $\Phi_a[ t ]$ of the "*device under test*",
- the [total phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Oscillator_model) $\Phi_b[ t ]$ of the "*reference*",
- and other parameters as needed, such as perhaps the [nominal angular frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance#Oscillator_model), $\omega_a$ and $\omega_b$, of the device under test and of the reference, respectively
  ?