# How can I estimate meta-uncertainty?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, metrology

A [type A uncertainty estimate](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Uncertainty/typea.html) is derived from repeated measurements.  For example, I may estimate the uncertainty on a measurement by repeating the measurement $N$ times and then calculating some measure of its dispersion, such as the standard deviation or, as below, the Allan deviation (suitable when $y$ might vary slowly over time):

$$u_y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(N-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} (y_{i+1} - y_i)^2}$$

If circumstances prevent me from taking any more measurements, how can I use the distribution of $y$ to estimate the meta-uncertainty $u_u$, (i.e. the uncertainty of the uncertainty)?

[image: u-meta]
[Source: XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2110/)

Comment: I saw now this old question of yours. If you're still interested in the answer, I can provide it, with some references, also for the Allan deviation. It might take some time, but let me know.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thanks for the offer. In reality, I have no practical need for an answer any more, as I am meanwhile working on a different topic.

Comment: Anyway I've bookmarked this and if I find the time I'll write an answer anyway since it's a very specialized topic, something I'm very fond of, and it might be useful to contribute to the spread of certain topics (I've already written a bit about the Allan variance in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/606244/111969)).